# Why the massive product update via admin isn't working?

Tags: magento2, admin, stock

I'm just updated all my 12k products via admin massive action, I changed the **stock status** to **in stock**, but it's not running.

[image: Magento 2 Message is added to queue]

How could I force it to run and fix it the next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queue system is managed via **RabbitMQ**, saying that, if you don't have it configured and the CRON as well, you won't have it working. [Configure it via the official DevDocs tutorial](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html).

This issue might happen when the CRON is blocked by something else.

#### Forcing the execution

To force it via terminal you just need to run this command below.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento queue:consumer:start product_action_attribute.update
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento queue:consumer:start product_action_attribute.website.update
```

Comment: If you don't use RabbitMQ you need to have the magento cron configured so that it runs the consumers.